# Counting Columns using R based on 2 Different Conditions

Tags: r, dataset, conditional-statements, counting

To preface this, I am relatively new to R and it's capabilities and have been struggling with this for about 2 weeks now. I have a rather large data set that has 2 columns Email and Status. It shows a like this:

```
Email        Status
fake@123     Subscribed
real@123     Subscribed
fake@123     Unsubscribed
real@123     Subscribed
```

I need to get the count of the emails that have changed status as well as the count of the emails that have the same status. So:

```
Count of New Unsubscribed = 1 since fake@123 changed from Subscribed to Unsub
Count of Existing Subscribed = 1 since real@123 stay Subscribed
```

I've tried all kinds of different things in R such as subsetting, if statements, loops, anti_joins, merges, and nothing seems to be working. If anyone can shed any light on this issue I will be very grateful. Thank you for your help in advance and I hope I explained my situation clearly.

Comment: You might start with `xtabs(~Email+Status, data=x)` to tabulate it; that may be enough for you, or you can use that data for further analysis.

Comment: @r2evans so if the statuses = 1 that means they changed correct? there's no real way to see which way the change happened? Say from subscribed to unsubscribed or unsubscribed to subscribed.

Comment: I didn't have time to do much coding before, so I just posted what I knew. Your expected output is vague: why do you base your reporting on row 3? I'm inferring that there are more rules at play, but perhaps this data is a little over-simplified (not something I say often or lightly!).

Comment: I essentially need to see if an email went from one status to another or stayed in that same status, I actually have two data sets from day to day that I combined to make one because I thought it would be easier to get the results.

Comment: @r2evans ^ if that helps explain the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
    x <- x[order(x[,1]),]
    email <- x[1,1]
    subscribe <- x[1,2]
    same_count <- 0
    change_count <- 0

    for(i in 2:nrow(x)){
      if(email == x[i,1] && subscribe == x[i,2]) { same_count <- same_count + 1}
      if(email == x[i,1] && subscribe != x[i,2]) { change_count <- change_count + 1}
      email <- x[i,1]
      subscribe <- x[i,2]
    }
```